# Is there a way to get notified if a post I down-voted gets edited?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have seen on this site questions, mainly by new users, that "forget" to put a reference to a notable claim, and some answers that forget to their credible sources. Those posts get down-votes, as they should. However, I've seen that when those post are fixed, ether by someone else or by the OP. The problem is that many people don't go back to check if the posts they down voted were fixed, which causes good posts to have down-votes from their past.

In order to avoid it, I sometimes go over my down-votes list, to check if posts have been edited or change in a way that fixes them. The problem is that I'm sure that many users don't do it, hence the answers that still have unjustified down votes, Is there a way to make a reminder system, that will encorage people to review their down-votes when an edit has accord to the post.

This is more crucial for questions.

a. because there is a greater chance of an questions to "forget" to put the notable claims, and then fixed.

b. Because there isn't insensitive in the form of regaining lost reputation by un down-voting.

Comment: I’d love that tfeature.

Answer (score 1):

As an individual, you can click on the star to mark the question as a favourite.

This doesn't address the bigger picture of encouraging everyone to do it.

Comment: I was just about to answer the same.

Comment: This proves Sklivvz and Oddthinking is the same person, they otherwise must have hivemind, which seems not very plausible! It's the secert of Oddthinkings avatar! [S] stands for Sklivvz!

Comment: It would be interesting if everyone employs this strategy.  The questions on -10, will have 10 stars lol.

Answer (score 1):

Something about Fabian's answer suggested a technical solution to me. Here's the basic scenario.

```
 When:
    * A voter votes for a question or answer (especially for downvotes, but also for upvotes).
    * The post is edited.
    * There is a clear direction of the voting prior to the edit
        e.g. at least 5 votes and at least 4 in every 5 votes are in the same direction. 
    * The voter voted in that direction, prior to the edit.
    * There is a clear, opposite, direction to the voting after the edit.
        e.g. at least 4 of the next 5 votes are in the opposite direction 
        or at least 2 voters changed their votes, into the new direction.
    * The user has not changed their vote since the edit.
    * The user has not visited the post since the edit (assuming this is recorded)
    * AND, the user has not received more than two similar notifications since their last visit
      (so as not to swamp people when they log in)

  Then:
    * The user should receive a notification indicating that a previous post has "turned around";
      they may like to revisit it to reconsider their vote.
```

Comment: I like this this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

My personal solution to this is to not downvote questions for a lack of notability. Unless I find the question bad for some other reason, I don't use downvotes on such questions. One exception is users that should know better, I tend to downvote those if they ignore the notability requirements.

I'd welcome a way to generally be able to revisit past voting and closing decisions in cases where there is some evidence that enough changed to reverse my previous decision. But such a mechanism would likely have to be opt-in as it could be rather noisy.